# Setting PATH on Wayland Gnome

Tags: gnome, environment-variables, wayland

I am left baffled how to correctly set PATH under Gnome Wayland (using Manjaro 19.x)

I want to set `PATH=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}:${GOROOT}/bin`

GOROOT is set in .config/environment.d/go.conf as

```
GOROOT=$HOME/opt/go
```

What I tried:

- `$HOME/.pam_environment`:

  ```
  PATH DEFAULT=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}:${GOROOT}/bin
  ```

  `PATH` is *somehow* set: `$HOME/bin` is added twice (why?)  and the expansion of `GOROOT` doesn't happen. It seems that systemd setting environment variables in `$HOME/.environment.d/*.conf` happens later than pam?
- `$HOME/.config/environment.d/*.conf` works for many variables I try to set in there but `PATH` is ignored.
- setting `PATH` in `.profile` is ignored

Comment: Do you have a `~/.bash_profile` file? If you do, and use `bash`, `~/.profile` would be ignored.

Comment: Yes, that DID work! I am really astonished that this works as I am a relatively new Wayland Plasma --> Wayland Gnome convert and setting environment variables in bash* config files did not work there. Still confused as why setting PATH in `config/envirionemnt.d/*.conf` does not work.

Comment: You are consistently misspelling "environment" as "envirionemnt" or "environemnt" maybe that's why?

Comment: Yes, misspelled, sorry, on the file system I use environment

Answer (score 1):

The [comment of John Doe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578046/setting-path-on-wayland-gnome#comment1075630_578046) is the correct answer: setting PATH in `.profile` works if there's no `.bash_profile`.